# Representing octal number as a str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method like this

```
def _changePerms(path, perms):
    try:
        os.chmod(path, perms)
        log.debug("Setting permission of file " + path + " to " + str(perms))
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

and I call the method like

```
_changePerms(path,0o755)
```

But my output log prints this:

```
2016-03-01 18:51:41,716 Setting permission of file path to 493
```

I would like to print the number in its octal form, instead of the decimal form (octal `755` == decimal `493`).

How do I print the value as a string?

Comment: 755 in octal (base 8) = 493 in decimal (base 10)

Comment: Because you're explicitly using octal notation...

Comment: so how do I convert an octal to str ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the string representation of a number is in base 10. To output it as an octal number, you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
log.debug(f"Setting permission of file '{path}' to {perms:o}")
```

or

```
log.debug("Setting permission of file '{}' to {:o}".format(path, perms))
```

`'o'` in the format specifier stands for 'octal format'.

Comment: yes ! This does it. Thanks :) . Also can you pls explain how :o changes the value to string ?

Comment: @ViChU: `{}` inserts the text of the next argument.  `{2}` inserts the text of the second argument.  `{:o}` inserts the next argument represented as an an octal string.  You can also specify minimum widths, precision of floating point numbers, and lots of other formats.  See the fine documentation.

Answer (score 3):

> Here I don't know why it prints 0o755 prints 493

Because they're the very same value, one in octal, one in decimal:

```
>>> 0o755
493
>>> '{:o}'.format(0o755)
'755'
```

Once converted to a numeric value, the int object it's stored in doesn't indicate what base was originally used. Octal is in this case used because Unix file permissions are convenient to group in 3-bit groups: you get one digit each for owner, group and other permissions (each of which contains read, write and execute bits). Other common bases include 2 (binary), 16 (hexadecimal) and 64 (base64 - used to transfer binary data in text protocols such as email).

Answer (score 0):

## Convert String (6 digits) to octal permission code in java

SymbolicToOctal("rw-r-----");

public static String SymbolicToOctal(String permString)
{

```
    String octalPerm = "";

    String ocatalString = "";
    int secondInd = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        if (x == 0) {
            ocatalString = permString.substring((x * 3), x + 3);
            secondInd = x + 3;
        } else {
            ocatalString = permString.substring((x * 3), (secondInd +3));
            secondInd = secondInd +3;
        }

        octalPerm += CalculatePermissionSum(ocatalString);
    }
    return octalPerm;

}


   public static int CalculatePermissionSum(String permString)
{
    int octalPerm = 0;

    for (char a: permString.toCharArray())
    {
        switch (a)
        {
            case 'r':
                octalPerm += 4;
                break;
            case 'w':
                octalPerm += 2;
                break;
            case 'x':
                octalPerm += 1;
                break;
            case '-':
                octalPerm += 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    return octalPerm;
}
```